# error #1452 - assign FK twice for the same PK

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I got this error - #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails.

I guess is I try to assign multiple foreign key to a primary key, or it is not?

my table look like this

```
user
=====
uId (PK)

friend
======
uId (FK of user.uId)
friendId

order
======
oderId
uId (FK of user.uId) <-- not sure this is possible or not
```

Comment: yes it is possible. now, could you show the create table code?

Comment: You should show the code you are using for the `update` or `insert`, as well as the data in the tables.

Comment: solved. it's cause by I've data within the columns.

Answer (score 0):

You might trying to insert into order and friend a fk user id value ,which  does not exist in user table.

Answer (score 0):

yes It's possible.  you can assign multiple foreign key to a primary key.

> You're getting this error because you're trying to add/update a row to
>   **table2/table3** that does not have a valid value for the **uId** field based
>   on the values currently stored in table1. If you post some more code I
>   can help you diagnose the specific cause.